# Add value to label inside nested collection view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to be able to set the text label inside a nested collection view.
I can show each of the values inside a print statement but when I assign it to the UILabel I get an `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I'm loading in the data from the parent collection view and assigning it to the data source:

```
private var timeZone: [AlternativeTimeZone]!
var setTimeZones: [AlternativeTimeZone] {
    get {
        return self.timeZone
    }
    set {
        self.timeZone = newValue
    }
}

childcollectionviewService.setTimeZones = alternateTimesZonesData
```

The service is an external class which houses all reference to the parent collection view in order to keep the view controller small.

My nested collection view code looks standard.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AlternateTimeZoneCell", for: indexPath) as? AlternateTimeZoneCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    print("Time Zone:", timeZone[indexPath.row].time)
    cell.alternateTime.text = timeZone[indexPath.row].time
    return cell
}
```

`AlternativeTimeZone` is a simple struct with a text string property. I am inside a nested collection view so could that indexPath be overriding the childs?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a broken outlet link in the cell template for the field `alternateTime` in your `AlternateTimeZoneCell`. Check to see if that's nil in the cell that you load. Also check to see if the dequeue is succeeding.

Comment: Dequeue is succeeding as I scroll through each cell and it prints out the result to the console. The cell is inside the collection view via storyboard and is associated with it inside the identity inspector. The resuable name is also set.

Comment: Okay, but if you look at the cell you dequeue, is its `alternateTime` property nil? Outlets are set up as "implicitly unwrapped optionals" by default, so if the outlet is not connected, you'll crash when you try to refer to it.

Comment: Yes `alternateTime` is nil.

Comment: That is what's causing your crash. It's almost certainly declared as implicitly unwrapped (`@IBOutlet alternateTime: UILabel!`). That syntax allows you to reference the property as if it's not an optional, but you will crash if it's nil. As a result, unconnected outlets cause crashes very early, which forces you to find and fix them early.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by removing the data source and delegate declaration into the `awakeFromNib` method as it turns out the `init` was trying to set the `alternateTime` value before the data was given to it.